# Xcode warns about missing protocol definition, even though @protocol is used

Tags: objective-c, xcode, protocols, forward-declaration

Since I had a import-cycle recently, I'm moving all `#import` statements (concerning my own files) from the header into the corresponding `.m`-file. I also added `@class` and `@protocol` forward-declarations to soothe the compiler. However, I still get he following warning:

```
Cannot find the protocol definition for 'MyCustomDelegate'.
```

As I said, there is an `@protocol MyCustomDelegate` before I use it in the `@interface`-Block. Interestingly this warning only occurs if the corresponding delegate is declared in another file (whose header is imported in the `.m`-file).

I read that one solution is to declare the delegate in a separate header file and import that file directly in the header of the class that implements the delegate. Is this really the way to go? Are there any other solutions? I think those delegates already bloated our code enough, now I should go on and even declare an own file for it?

Small sample code to better illustrate the problem:

NewFooController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol NewFooControllerDelegate;

@interface NewFooController : UITableViewController
  @property (nonatomic, weak) id<NewFooControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol NewFooControllerDelegate
@end
```

HomeTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol NewFooControllerDelegate;

// warning points to line below
@interface HomeTableViewController : UITableViewController <NewFooControllerDelegate>
@end
```

HomeTableViewController.m

```
#import "HomeTableViewController.h"
#import "NewFooController.h"
@implementation HomeTableViewController
@end
```

Comment: Where do you import NewFooController.h?

Comment: Sorry, I copy & pasted part of the code. ;) I changed the `#import "NewTaskController.h"` to `#import "NewFooController.h`.

Answer (score -1):

HomeTableViewController.h references the protocol, but it hasn't been declared yet.
If you import NewTaskController.h in HomeTableViewController.h before it attempts to use it, it should solve your problem.

Of course you can then remove the import from HomeTableViewController.m

Comment: I know that it has not been declared and I know that importing it in the header would solve the problem. However, the reason I moved the imports from the header to the `.m`-file were import-cycles. So I need a solution which gets rid of the warning *and can not lead to import-cycles*. As I posted, a viable option is to write the protocol declaration into a separate file. I just want to know if there are more solutions, which fits my needs.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is "best way", but try import header of class that implement protocol before class header file.

HomeTableViewController.m

```
#import "NewFooController.h"
#import "HomeTableViewController.h"

@implementation HomeTableViewController
@end
```

And you can remove protocol declaration in HomeTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HomeTableViewController : UITableViewController <NewFooControllerDelegate>
@end
```